# How to add derived variables to a ResultSet

Tags: scala, anorm

Almost all guides/tutorials that I've seen only show how to parse values  from columns that are directly available in the database. For example, the following is a very common pattern, and I understand how it can be useful in many ways:

```
case class Campaign(id: Int, campaign_mode_id: Int, name: String)

class Application @Inject()(db: Database) extends Controller {

  val campaign = {
    get[Int]("campaign.id") ~
    get[Int]("campaign.campaign_mode_id") ~
    get[String]("campaign.name") map {
      case id ~ campaign_mode_id ~ name  => Campaign(id, campaign_mode_id, name)
    }
  }

  def index = Action {
    val data : List[Campaign] = db.withConnection { implicit connection =>
      SQL("SELECT id, campaign_mode_id, name FROM campaign").as(campaign.*)
    }

    Ok(Json.toJson(data))
  }
}
```

And it'd produce a result that might look like the following:

```
[
    {
        id: 2324,
        campaign_mode_id: 13,
        name: "ABC"
    },
    {
        id: 1324,
        campaign_mode_id: 23,
        name: "ABCD"
    }   
]
```

Now what if there were an additional date field in the campaign table like `started_on` that referred to when the campaign was started? Or another field called `num_followers` that was an integer referring to the number of followers?

And suppose that I wanted to do some calculations after running the DB query and before returning my JSON. For example, I want to include a `latest_compaign_date` that references the `started_on` date of the newest campaign. Or say that I wanted to include an `average_num_followers` that referred to the average number of followers for all campaigns.

My final result would look like:

```
{
    latest_compaign_date: 12 Dec 2018,
    average_num_followers: 123,
    campaigns: [
        {
            id: 2324,
            campaign_mode_id: 13,
            name: "ABC"
        },
        {
            id: 1324,
            campaign_mode_id: 23,
            name: "ABCD"
        }   
    ]
}
```

I know that for the examples I've given it's better to do those calculations in my DB query and not in my application code. But what if I had to do something really complicated and wanted to do it in my application code for some reason? How should I modify my ResutSetParser to facilitate this?

Here are a couple of approaches that I've tried:

### Do not use ResultSetParser and instead do everything manually

```
  case class CampaignData(newestCampaignDate: Long, newestCampaignId: Long, averageNumFollowers: Float, campaigns: Seq[Campaign])

  def aggregater(rows: Seq[Row]): CampaignData = {
    val newestCampaignDate: Long = getNewestDate(rows)
    val newestCampaignId: Long = getNewestCampaign(rows)
    val averageNumFollowers: Float = getAverageNumFollowers(rows)

    val campaigns: Seq[Campaign] = rows.map(row => {
      val rowMap: Map[String, Any] = row.asMap

      Campaign(
        rowMap("campaign.id").asInstanceOf[Int],
        rowMap("campaign.campaign_mode_id") match { case None => 0 case Some(value) => value.asInstanceOf[Int]},
        rowMap("campaign.name") match { case None => "" case Some(value) => value.asInstanceOf[String]}
      )
    })

    CampaignData(newestCampaignDate, newestCampaignId, averageNumFollowers, campaigns)
  }

  def index = Action {
    val data : Seq[Row] = db.withConnection { implicit connection =>
      SQL("SELECT id, campaign_mode_id, name, started_on, num_followers FROM campaign")
    }

    Ok(Json.toJson(aggregater(data)))
  }
```

This approach smells bad because having to deal with every field using `asInstanceOf` and `match` is very tedious and honestly feels unsafe. And also intuitively, I feel that Anorm should have something better for this since I'm probably not the first person who has run into this problem.

### Use ResultSetParser in combination with another function

```
case class Campaign(id: Int, campaign_mode_id: Int, name: String)
case class CampaignData(newestCampaignDate: Long, newestCampaignId: Long, averageNumFollowers: Float, campaigns: Seq[Campaign])

val campaign = {
  get[Int]("campaign.id") ~
  get[Int]("campaign.campaign_mode_id") ~
  get[Int]("campaign.num_followers") ~
  get[Long]("campaign.started_on") ~
  get[String]("campaign.name") map {
    case id ~ campaign_mode_id ~ num_followers ~ started_on ~ name  => Map(
      "id" -> id, 
      "campaign_mode_id" -> campaign_mode_id, 
      "num_followers" -> num_followers,
      "started_on" -> started_on,
      "name" -> name
    )
  }
}

def index = Action {
  val data : Map[String, Any] = db.withConnection { implicit connection =>
    SQL("SELECT id, campaign_mode_id, name, started_on, num_followers FROM campaign").as(campaign.*)
  }

  Ok(Json.toJson(aggregator(data)))
}

def aggregator(data: Map[String, Any]): CampaignData = {
  val newestCampaignDate: Long = getNewestDate(data)
  val newestCampaignId: Long = getNewestCampaign(data)
  val averageNumFollowers: Float = getAverageNumFollowers(data)
  val campaigns: Seq[Campaign] = getCampaigns(data)

  CampaignData(newestCampaignDate, newestCampaignId, averageNumFollowers, campaigns)
}
```

This approach is better in the sense that I don't have to deal with `isInstanceOf`, but then there is a bigger problem of having to deal with the intermediate `Map`. And it makes all the getter functions (e.g. `getCampaigns`) so much more complicated. I feel that Anorm has to offer something better out of the box that I'm not aware of.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Hey I added a couple of approaches I've tried so far

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you posted in your first code snippet, the following code

```
def index = Action {
    val data : List[Campaign] = db.withConnection { implicit connection =>
      SQL("SELECT id, campaign_mode_id, name FROM campaign").as(campaign.*)
    }

    Ok(Json.toJson(data))
  }
```

returns a typesafe List of Campaign thanks to Anorm extractors.

Typically, you will pre-process the result with a typesafe function like so

```
case class CampaignAggregateData(campaigns:List[Campaign], averageNumFollowers:Int, newestCampaignId:Option[Long])

def aggregate(f:List[Campaign]):CampaignAggregatedData

def index = Action {
    val manyCampaign : List[Campaign] = db.withConnection { implicit connection =>
      SQL("SELECT id, campaign_mode_id, name FROM campaign").as(campaign.*)
    }

    val aggregatedData:CampaignAggregateData = aggregate(manyCampaign)

    Ok(Json.toJson(data))
  }
```

In cases where you would need aggregation to be executed by the database engine, you would typically have multiple `db.withConnection` statements inside a single action